# Explain beginning of "Magen Avot"

Tags: shabbat, tefilla, maariv, leil-shabbat

During the Friday night service, there is a short paragraph that begins:

> מגן אבות **בדברו**

My translation: "The shield of the fathers, with his saying"

What does the term בדברו mean in this context? What saying?

Comment: He said he would protect and he protected.

Comment: It's parallel to במאמרו in the next phrase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The “saying” is part of [Braishis 15(1)](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8210)

> אַחַר הַדְּבָרִים הָאֵלֶּה הָיָה דְבַר ה' אֶל אַבְרָם בַּמַּחֲזֶה
>   לֵאמֹר **אַל תִּירָא אַבְרָם אָנֹכִי מָגֵן לָךְ** שְׂכָרְךָ הַרְבֵּה
>   מְאֹד.
>
> After these incidents, the word of the Lord came to Abram in a vision,
>   saying, **"Fear not, Abram; I am your Shield;** your reward is exceedingly great."

as pointed out by the commentary Eitz Yosef on the siddur, found in the siddur [אוצר התפילות.](http://www.moshebooks.com/items/421592-%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA-)

Comment: That is a 'saying' ABOUT protection, but it doesn't seem to be an instance of 'saying' CAUSING protection.  Unless he means that that statement triggered the protection? Or he means that 'bdvaro' doesn't mean 'using His word to do so'?